# How to revert Git soft reset?

Tags: git, git-revert

I was working on a branch and by accident I've done `git reset HEAD~1` because I thought I'm resetting my last commit.

The problem is that I didn't even commit my changes so I've done reset to commit which was done by someone else. A lot of changes in that commit were done on files on which I was also working on so I didn't notice and continued my work. After I've committed and pushed my changes, I've noticed missing commit.

```
develop branch: commitA -> commitB -> commitC

my branch: commitA -> commitB -> myCommit
```

Is there any way to revert those changes and insert `commitC` before my commit?

Comment: `git commit -a -s -c ORIG_HEAD`, but it will not include added files, you have to run `git add ...<list of files>...` beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

You can see your working tree by `git reflog`. First, back to `commitC` and pick your `myCommit` top of `git log` stack. Then just update remote.

```
$ git reflog
# copy the commit-hash of 'commitC'

$ git checkout <commitC-hash>
$ git reflog
# copy the 'myCommit-hash'

$ git cherry-pick  <myCommit-hash>         # take the 'commitC' top
$ git checkout -b 'new-my-branch'          # create 'new-my-branch' from current stage

# Replace 'my-branch' with 'new-my-branch'
$ git branch -D my-branch                  # delete 'my-branch'
$ git checkout -b my-branch                # create new 'my-branch' from 'new-y-branch'
$ git push -f origin HEAD                  # replace remote/my-branch by local/my-branch
```

Comment: It's too way far from simple solution you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to revert your commit, because you can *rebase* your local branch on the remote one, and cleanly bring in `commitC` before reapplying your commit on top of that.

I don't know exactly what you have done locally to end up with the branch diagrams you showed us, but I think that you can simply rebase your branch on the remove `develop` to pull in `commitC`, and then replay your `myCommit` on top of it:

```
git fetch origin           # bring origin/develop up to date
git checkout develop       # checkout local develop branch
git rebase origin/develop  # rebase your local branch on the remote one
```

Now you should be able to simply fast-forward the remote branch via:

```
git push origin develop
```

Comment: Too complicated. `git rebase --onto origin/develop HEAD~1`

Comment: @0andriy You say that my answer is too complicated when the one receiving the upvotes is way more complex.  Also, I don't think we need `rebase --onto` here.